# Recent changes to Rally C# REST API?

Tags: rally

1)      Earlier this week I was able to create defects and testcases using the Create method, which took 2 arguments at the time (a string and the DynamicJsonObject). However now, it needs three. I understand that one of these is now the workspace reference. How do I go about getting the workspace reference? For creating defects and testcases, I am using an empty string, and this seems to be working correctly for me. Is this to be expected?

2)      For creating test case results, I am having a bit of trouble.

```
        DynamicJsonObject newTCResult = new DynamicJsonObject();
        newTCResult["Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        newTCResult["TestCase"] = "/testcase/11271454106";
        newTCResult["Notes"] = "test";
        newTCResult["Build"] = "13.1.0.90";
        newTCResult["Verdict"] = "Pass";

        CreateResult cr = restApi.Create(" ", "TestCaseResult", newTCResult);
```

As of right now, absolutely nothing is happening when I run this. I was able to do this successfully earlier this week (when I was able to use the Create method with two arguments). I feel that the problem is because I don't have a valid workspace reference. I followed the suggestion of another user in a similar question prior to this which worked for earlier, however now I am having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this. It appears that the date field needs to be converted to UTC, so my code now looks something like this

newTCResult["Date"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");

After making that small change results were working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat surprising that Creates on Stories or Defects work with an empty string for a Workspace ref, although I suspect that on the server-side, the Webservices API is just using Default Workspace for the User of concern.

Either way, here's how you can get a ref to the Workspace of interest:

```
        String myWorkspaceName = "My Workspace";

        // Get a Reference to Target Workspace
        Request workspaceRequest = new Request("workspace");
        workspaceRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
            {
                "Name",
                "ObjectID"
            };

        workspaceRequest.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, myWorkspaceName);
        QueryResult workspaceQueryResults = restApi.Query(workspaceRequest);

        var targetWorkspace = workspaceQueryResults.Results.First();
        Console.WriteLine("Found Target Workspace: " + targetWorkspace["Name"]);

        String workspaceRef = targetWorkspace["_ref"];
```

You can then use `workspaceRef` in your call to `restApi.Create()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. That seems to have worked (at least for creating the test case), though I still seem to be having the same problem with creating a test case result. Perhaps my formatting of the OID for the newTCResult["TestCase"] is in correct? I've just tried the OID as well as /testcase/OID and still get the same outcome.

Comment: What happens if you inspect your Errors/Warnings collection on cr, i.e.:

Comment: `List<string> createErrors = cr.Errors;
                List<string> createWarnings = cr.Warnings;

                // Summarize errors/warnings
                Console.WriteLine("Create Errors:");
                for (int j = 0; j < createErrors.Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(createErrors[j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Create Warnings:");
                for (int j = 0; j < createWarnings.Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(createWarnings[j]);
                }`

Comment: I am getting the following: Could not update: Could not write changes in Unit Of Work. Create Warning: API status is Deprecated and will become Not Supported on 2014-03-15

Comment: What happens if you bypass the .NET API completely and POST against `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/testcaseresult/create` with the following payload: `<TestCaseResult>
<Build>2345</Build>
<Date>2012-12-11T23:05:49.365Z</Date>
<TestCase ref="/testcase/12345678910"/>
<Tester ref="/user/12345678911"/>
<Verdict>Pass</Verdict>
</TestCaseResult>` Note you'll need to replace the TestCase and Tester OID's with ones appropriate to your workspace. If you have Chrome - Simple REST Client is a handy plugin for making REST requests.

Comment: That works correctly using the Simple REST Client for chrome. I get a new test case result associated to the test case in question

Comment: I'm not sure where things are going wrong. The above C# sample code works  for me in creating TCR's. You might try the C# code against several different TC's to see if the issue is restricted to one particular TC. Also make sure that the TC is in the same workspace as you've specified in your workspaceRef.

Comment: This is definitely very odd. I only have the one workspace, and I've tried several other test cases and I'm getting the same error. Really strange...

Comment: Just to add an update. I tried another Rally account and I'm still getting the same errors. I guess it is specific to this workspace? But I'm still not sure what the problem could be...